# CakePHP 3: How to display sum of values in column from finder results

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

```
CakePHP: 3.1.4
```

I have a custom finder function in my table that gets all records from this month with the row "fee" holding a decimal value.

In a view I want to display the sum of fee values from this selection with a variable. I tried to figure it out with help of the book [Using SQL Functions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html)
but I don't understand how to use the syntax correctly in my case.

Custom finder in Table:

```php
class TicketsTable extends Table
{
    // find all tickets created this month
    public function findThismonths(Query $query, array $options){

    // get first and last day of month
    $first_day_this_month = date('m-01-Y');
    $last_day_this_month  = date('m-t-Y');

    $query
    ->select(['id', 'created', 'fee', 'extend_fee'])
    ->where([ function($exp) {
        $first_day_this_month = date('Y-m-01'); 
        $last_day_this_month  = date('Y-m-t');
        return $exp->between('Tickets.created', $first_day_this_month, $last_day_this_month, 'date');
    }]);

    return $query;
}
```

I can easily get the count of records but I don't understand this works with a sum.

Controller:

```php
class CashpositionsController extends AppController
{
public function overview()
{

    $tickets = TableRegistry::get('Tickets');
    $thismonths = $tickets->find('thismonths'); // get records with finder
    $thismonths_count = $thismonths->count();   // get count of records

    // that's what I want but this syntax does not exist in Cake...
    $thismonths_sum = $thismonths->sum('fee'); // *nope*

    // set to display in view 
    $this->set('thismonths_count', $thismonths_count);
    $this->set('thismonths_sum', $thismonths_sum);
```

Then in the view:

```php
<tr>
    <td>Number of tickets:</td>
    <td><?= $thismonths_count ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Sum of cash:</td>
    <td><?= $thismonth_sum ?></td>
</tr>

<?php foreach ($thismonths as $ticket): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?= h($ticket->id) ?> </td>
    <td><?= h($ticket->created) ?> </td>
    <td><?= h($ticket->fee) ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

In the book there is this example:

```php
// Results in SELECT COUNT(*) count FROM ...
$query = $articles->find();
$query->select(['count' => $query->func()->count('*')]);
```

But I can't get sth like this to work for me either with sum().

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use Collection [(manual)](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html#aggregation)

```
$thismonths_sum = $thismonths->sumOf('fee');
```

Comment: Aaah, I never made the connection that I could use Collection ;). Thanks a lot!! Works great!

Comment: Do you know if there's also a way to do this with two properties and not just one? There's no example for it in the book.

Comment: I mean if I want the sum of all values of two columns. Is that possible?

Comment: well, apart from doing `$thismonths->sumOf('fee') + $thismonths->sumOf('extend_fee'); ` you can create a calculated field in your query or a virtual property in your entity and then sumOf that field

Comment: Oh yes, sorry...that first one was kind of obvious I just noticed ^^. Thanks for your fast help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this like below:

```
$totalFee = $this->find();
$totalFee->where([function ($exp) {
           $first_day_this_month = date('Y-m-01');
           $last_day_this_month  = date('Y-m-t');
           return $exp->between('Tickets.created', $first_day_this_month, $last_day_this_month, 'date');
            }
            ]
        );
$totalFee = $totalFee->select(['total' => $totalFee->func()->sum('fee')])->first();
```